# net links on meteor ios simulator can not click in

Tags: ios, meteor, simulator

When I do the meteor run iOS in my project it threw no error:

1.Started proxy.
 2.Started MongoDB.
 3.Started your app.

**App running at: http://localhost:3000/**

Started app on iOS Simulator. 
But the links on the ios simulator screen can not click in,it has no action at all when click the links of the blue characters,the detail screen is in the attached picture. [image]ios simulator screen of the project

Answer (score 0):

have you been sure that the click button is enabled

Comment: the click button is able,when click it it can add one time,but the links in blue characters can not link in,when click the net links it can not forward to the link adress.

Comment: it seems that you'd like to push to an new view /webview controller or call  a new UIView after you pressed the links?

Comment: but the blue characters links can be clicked in and forward to the link dress when open this page in internet explore,so it just can not click in on simulator, whether android or ios simulator it won't work.

Comment: have you added` App Transport Security Settings `to Info.plist?

Comment: the HTML content is like below:                                                         <template name="info">
  <h2>Learn Meteor!</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.meteor.com/try" target="_blank">Do the Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://guide.meteor.com" target="_blank">Follow the Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://docs.meteor.com" target="_blank">Read the Docs</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://forums.meteor.com" target="_blank">Discussions</a></li>
  </ul>
</template>

Comment: no,i did not add ` App Transport Security Settings `to Info.plist,how should i add it,can you give me an example? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I mean the following:

[yourProject/Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k56Gb.png)

Comment: sorry,i just first use meteor and don't know where the Info.plist is,can you tell me?Thanks very much.

Comment: I find it under /platforms/ios/myapp/myapp.plist,is this to be set?

Comment: I added myapp-info.plist with: Allow Arbitrary Loads YES,and rerun meteor run ios,but the links still can not be clicked in.

Comment: And I tested on real android and ios phone, the app can be loaded on phone successfully, but also the links can not be clicked in and be opened and forward to the link address, only in internet explore the links can click in and forward to the linked address.

Comment: I looked into the meteor document,maybe need to set the mobile-config.js in one meteor project about the access rule, but i can not be sure,can you give me some example of mobile-config.js about access rules?

Comment: did you have  a gitHub account (https://github.com/ :you can push your code the website and it will be easier to manager your project )?you can show me your code ,then the error will be easier to be found .or you can email your code to me.(my email address:louchu0604@gmail.com)